# Twilio Ruby Gem calls.create param - adding r.Say message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to add the option of adding a spoken message before a prerecorded message plays in my outbound calls. The closest question of this this type I could find was this [Does Twilio Ruby Gem Take Other Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016157/does-the-twilio-ruby-gem-take-parameters-other-than-from-to-and-url-when)

I currently have a form where you enter the number you want to call and field for the message you'd like to

```
<form action="calls" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="number e.g. 2124095555" />
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="add a message" />
    <input type="submit" value="Roll em!">
</form>
```

In my call's controller I have:

```
 def create

    data = {
      :from => CALLER_ID,
      :to => params['number'],
      :say => params['message'],
      :url => 'http://howenstine.co/rick_roll.mp3',
      :if_machine => 'Continue'
    }

    begin
      client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
      client.account.calls.create(data)
    rescue StandardError => bang
      redirect_to :action => '.', 'msg' => "Error #{bang}"
      return
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Obviously the :say param is not working. I've something like this for inbound calls, but I don't believe that will work for an outbound call

```
 def voice
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Say 'fooo bar', :voice => 'alice'
         r.Play 'http://linode.rabasa.com/cantina.mp3'
    end

    render_twiml response
  end
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When creating calls via the REST API, you need to send the `from`, `to` and either `url` or `applications_sid` parameters and there are a bunch of optional parameters, like `if_machine`, that you can send too. The [full list is available in the REST API documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional).

However, as you have discovered, you can't send a `say` parameter. In order to get the result you're looking for, you'll need use your voice endpoint url to read the message, then play the file.

Since you already have a voice endpoint, you will also need to decide at the time of the call what to do.

So, if you modify your `create` action to something like the following, which passes the message along to your voice url:

```
def create
  data = {
    :from => CALLER_ID,
    :to => params['number'],
    :url => voice_url(:message => params['message']),
    :if_machine => 'Continue'
  }

  begin
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
    client.account.calls.create(data)
  rescue StandardError => bang
    redirect_to :action => '.', 'msg' => "Error #{bang}"
    return
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Then in your voice endpoint, check for the message and return it, followed by the file you wanted to play, otherwise return what you had already.

```
def voice
  if params['message'].present?
    # if we have a message, say it followed by the rick roll
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Say params['message'], :voice => 'alice'
      r.Play 'http://howenstine.co/rick_roll.mp3'
    end
  else
    # otherwise return the original response
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Say 'fooo bar', :voice => 'alice'
      r.Play 'http://linode.rabasa.com/cantina.mp3'
    end
  end

  render_twiml response
end
```

Let me know if that helps at all.